# Database connection in mysql in AndroidStudio without PHP

Tags: java, android, mysql

### Actually i want to connect mysql with android without php

> I tried to print the data which is store on the mysql db.
>
> Database Name="android"
>   port number="3006"
>   sql="select * from tablename";

```
private class Data1 extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
                 @Override
                 protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                     Connection con= null;
                     String username="root";
                    String password="";
                     try {
                         Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                        con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.106:3306/android",username,password);
                         PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from login");
                         ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
                         while (rs.next()){
                             System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                        }
                        con.close();
                     } catch (SQLException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     finally {
                         System.out.println("ok");
                    }

                     return null;
                 }

            }
```

---

```
>E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>Process: com.example.login, PID: 10158
>java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
```

Comment: How are you executing the AsyncTask?

Comment: Data1 d=new Data1();
d.execute();

Comment: What line is causing the error? Can you print out the stacktrace?